# Weird scrolling with iOS 7, PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova, ios7

I am developing a very simple app, with a list of element, inside a page.
I am using PhoneGap with jQueryMobile.
To make a comparison, I used both the jQuery Mobile Listview and a custom implementation of the list. Both the implementations share the same problem.

I think that an image is better than a thousand of words...

[image: scrolling past the header]

As you can see in the image, the header is below the status bar, fixed and in foreground.
However, when I scroll the list, the elements override the phone status bar. What I would like to have, is that the elemnts "disapear" under the header, like in common iOS list.

How can I achieve this?

I put the relevant part of the CSS below.

```
[data-role=header]{
  z-index:100;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
}

/*
 * iOS7 NavBar Margin
 */
.myMarginClass
{
  margin-top : 20px;
}

.myMarginClass > [data-role=header]{
  z-index:100;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
}

.myMarginClass > [data-role=content]{   
  position:relative;
  top:40px;
}
```

The relevant HTML

```
<div data-role="page" class="myMarginClass" id="docListPage">
  <div data-role="header">
    [...]
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    [...]
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    [...]
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.
    Rik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Cordova/Phonegap 3.0? If yes this is a known bug, go to 3.1

http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/09/phonegap-and-cordova-with-ios-7/

PS - See here for a possible fix:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/nNUgSOfpt5Q

Comment: Thank you. The second link solved the issue. I had to patch a very small part of the native Objective-C code, but, at the end, it worked!